# What are the origins of "tricking"?

Tags: history, tricking

My wife recently introduced me to the practice of "tricking" (essentially, a form of martial arts demo that focuses on jumps and acrobatic maneuvers - in some ways, the martial arts version of parkour) - [video here for reference](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xK-zbjs92nw).  The art clearly has its roots in traditional martial arts but the core techniques seem borrowed from multiple disciplines. Is there any documented origin of tricking and how it developed?

Comment: I don't see how it's anything other than the natural evolution of jumping and spinning techniques, which have been around for ages. On a related side note, somebody tried a jumpy thing on me once; I put my hand on their chest while they were in the air and helped them to the ground--it was quite funny, and I looked like a superhero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This Yahoo article](http://voices.yahoo.com/the-history-martial-art-tricking-2345673.html) may help you. It details the origin and evolution of tricking since the early 1960s.  It draws from movie stunts, capoera, and parkour as source for the creation of tricking.

However, I have *no idea* how authentic or authoritative it is. Feel free to add to this answer.

Comment: It would help to summarize and paraphrase parts of the article and post that here.